# UK visa sponsor

Tags: uk

I'm applying for a UK visa to sit for plab exam, and I am thinking about making my dad a sponsor. I have two questions:

My father runs a private clinic, so providing an evidence of the average income will be hard. Will that affect the decision, and if yes how can I provide acceptable evidence of his income since he receives money in cash?

His bank account contains enough money but with too few transactions, as the money is derived from saving certificates interest. Will that bank statement be accepted?

Comment: Is there a reason you're planning on using a sponsor? It does not make your application stronger, contrary to some opinions.

Comment: My account doesn't have enough money, though it will be after 4 days because some of my saving certificates  will be encashed, but I have concerns regarding ECO thinking of funds parkings and I think they demand that   your account doesn't drop below the minimum required funds for the last  28 days

Answer (score 0):

I think you could include the savings account statements along with your main statements. This will help show where your money came from.

Does he keep company accounts? Tax records? Even a cash business should do this.